# Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-26.0-android.jar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-26.0-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

I working with flutter application I update firebase plugins in my pubspec file then suddenly this issue arises. I don't know how to solve this. please help

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


@IntelliJAmiya  please check

Answer (score 1):

add `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'` to your android projects build.gradle file. That'll solve this issue